# Why is a triangle not displayed?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw a triangle in GLFW:

```
//... init GLFW, compiling and linking shaders, init float array with vertices
//-- all success
GLuint VBO, VAO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexTriangle), vertexTriangle, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

//scene loop
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

After I start my program, it does not draw a triangle. It only draws an empty gray screen.

Comment: What color are you expecting your triangle to be?  Where in the code did you tell OpenGL that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vertex array object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) has to be bound when you do the draw call:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

In your code the `VAO` is not bound at this point, because the default vertex array object (0) is bound by `glBindVertexArray(0);`, right before the main loop.

The information about the vertex attributes is stored int the vertex array object. `glDrawArrays` uses the attribute information stored in the currently bound vertex array object to perform the drawing.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 10.3. VERTEX ARRAYS; page 347](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> The currently bound vertex array object is used for all commands which modify vertex array state, such as `VertexAttribPointer` and `EnableVertexAttribArray`; all commands which draw from vertex arrays, such as **`DrawArrays`** and `DrawElements`;